# Error occurred in deployment step 'add solution': Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, page-layout, solution-deployment

I'm getting this error trying to deploy my solution.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'add solution': Value does not fall
>   within the expected range

I' Using One Feature, and a Page Layout Module.
When I Change the wsp file to cab, I don't get the aspx page I have in the module, but I get two others, I have no idea why.

In addition, I Change the solution name and my Feature name, because of getting error that their name were too long.

Any ideas?